# Create new commands in terminal with fork() and exec()

Tags: c, linux, exec, fork

I would like to know how I can manipulate C program to run command in the terminal.

For example:
If I run this statement PS1="Linuxrocks $", it runs fine in the terminal.
But how would I write a program to do the the same thing. Or what function do I use?

```
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <unistd.h>

    int main() {
            char *argv[3] = {"Command-line", ".", NULL};

            int pid = fork();

            if ( pid == 0 ) {
                    execvp( PS1="linuxrocks $", argv );
            }

            wait( NULL );
        printf( "Finished executing the parent process\n" );

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Read about the [`setenv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv) function.

Comment: You want to write C program to change an enviroment variable in the environment you start the program from, so that the changes will still be available after the program had ended?

Comment: Yes. Let's say by default when I open terminal from Accessories it shows as 'os@debian:~$' as a root directory after I run the program it should show 'Linuxrocks $' instead of 'os@debian:~$' after the program stops running.

Comment: This is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Use shell scripting to change the currently active environment.

If you ran a binary program to do so it would only modifiy its own copy of the environment which it got assigned when started.

Changes to the latter are gone after the program ended, as the program's environment (the changes were applied to) will be gone by then.

Answer (score 0):

You can, and I do, set `PS1="New value: "` in an appropriate shell start-up file (such as `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or perhaps `.bashrc`).  If you `export PS1`, it becomes available to sub-shells too.  I don't export it so I can tell when I'm in a sub-shell.

You cannot do it as you attempted to do it.

Answer (score -2):

You should probably use function system() from stdlib.h.